# angular $watch empty value error

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, watch, angular-ngmodel

I have this in my controller :

```
     $scope.$watch('infos.location', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue.formatted_address == 'Erreur ...') {
            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: 'Geolocalisation',
                template: 'Voulez-vous activer la géolocalisation ?'
            });
            confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    $cordovaPreferences.show().success(function(value) {
                        //alert("Success: " + value);
                    }).error(function(error) {
                        // alert("Error: " + error);
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log('You are not sure');
                }
            });
        }
    }, true);
```

It watch this input :

```
<label  class="item item-input">*
   <ion-google-place placeholder="Veuillez saisir l'adresse du bien"  ng-model="infos.location"  current-location="true"/>
</label>
```

But when i open my view I have this error :

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newValue.formatted_address')
```

**How can I avoid this kind of error ? Is there a better solution to Watch this value 'Erreur ...' and start calling confirmPopup ?** Thank you.

Comment: how does `infos.location` get a property `.formatted_address` from this code?

Comment: It comes from the `"ion-google-place"` directive. It's an input, you click on it and you have your geolocation/ formatted_address and other stuff : https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place

Comment: you can't really do it this way, I think;  that code has promises that are being called and then the `ng-model` is being changed after the promises are returned;  your `$watch` is going to be fired at least twice each time the input is changed by the user, or maybe more.  you *could* put a guard statement like `if (newValue.formatted_address){`, but this is likely to have performance issues.

Comment: Ok, i knew it was not a good way to do that... So, how can I watch this value in an other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'infos.location'` isn't object, probably you haven't initialize it or initialize it as string.

*I would like to see how you initialized your `infos` object or whole controller.*

Probably, you could fix this by initializing `infos`.

```
infos: {
  location: {},
  ...
}
```

Or, if *ion-google-place* initialize `infos.location`, you can just check if `infos.location` (ie. `newValue` inside function) is (not) *`undefined`*, and just ignore (skip) that situation.

```
 $scope.$watch('infos.location', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && newValue.formatted_address == 'Erreur ...') {
            ...
        }
    }, true);
```

Comment: I initialzed infos object but not the location key ... So it's fixed thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

This is how i figured it out :

```
$scope.infos = {
      nom: '',
      tel: '',
      location: {},
      lat: '',
      lng: ''
  };
```

Then later in my Controller :

```
     $scope.$watch('infos.location', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue.formatted_address == 'Erreur ...') {
            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: 'Geolocalisation',
                template: 'Voulez-vous activer la géolocalisation ?'
            });
            confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    $cordovaPreferences.show().success(function(value) {
                        //alert("Success: " + value);
                    }).error(function(error) {
                        // alert("Error: " + error);
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log('You are not sure');
                }
            });
        }
    }, true);
```

infos.location was not initialized when i entered in my view. Now it works. Thank you all !